# How to add existing custom type to graphQl schema?

Tags: graphql

In my working project we use unusual approach to build graphql schema. Each entity has its own json model, where described entity parameters. Sample:

```
Customer: 
{
    "customerId": {
        "type": String
    },
    "customerName": {
        "type": String
    },
    customerProperties: {
        "type": object
        .... 
    },
}

Orders: 
{
   "customerId": {
        type: string
   },
   ///other details
}
```

In compilation stage many different custom utils revert it to graphql models and queries. For each entity system creates new type via "new GraphqlObjectType" taken from "npm graphql" library.
Now I need to make link from Customer type to Orders. Something like:

```
type Customer {
  id: String,
  name: String,
  orders: Orders
}
```

As I said before we don't have graphql schemas in pure form, just result of methods of graphql library like GraphqlObjectType.
Question! How can I add existing type to Customer schema?
If I try in our factory method to add something like add.type(new GraphqlObjectType({name : Orders})), system response me Error:
"**Schema must contains unique named types but contains multiple names "Orders"**". It is understandable why it responses this message. But how assign to schema existing data type having only name?

Answer (score -1):

```
We start with a special "root" object
We select the hero field on that
For the object returned by hero, we select the name and appearsIn fields
```

Because the shape of a GraphQL query closely matches the result, you can predict what the query will return without knowing that much about the server. But it's useful to have an exact description of the data we can ask for - what fields can we select? What kinds of objects might they return? What fields are available on those sub-objects? That's where the schema comes in.

Every GraphQL service defines a set of types which completely describe the set of possible data you can query on that service. Then, when queries come in, they are validated and executed against that schema.
Type language

GraphQL services can be written in any language. Since we can't rely on a specific programming language syntax, like JavaScript, to talk about GraphQL schemas, we'll define our own simple language. We'll use the "GraphQL schema language" - it's similar to the query language, and allows us to talk about GraphQL schemas in a language-agnostic way.
Object types and fields

The most basic components of a GraphQL schema are object types, which just represent a kind of object you can fetch from your service, and what fields it has. In the GraphQL schema language, we might represent it like this:

type Character {
name: String!
appearsIn: [Episode!]!
}

The language is pretty readable, but let's go over it so that we can have a shared vocabulary:

```
Character is a GraphQL Object Type, meaning it's a type with some fields. Most of the types in your schema will be object types.
name and appearsIn are fields on the Character type. That means that name and appearsIn are the only fields that can appear in any part of a GraphQL query that operates on the Character type.
String is one of the built-in scalar types - these are types that resolve to a single scalar object, and can't have sub-selections in the query. We'll go over scalar types more later.
String! means that the field is non-nullable, meaning that the GraphQL service promises to always give you a value when you query this field. In the type language, we'll represent those with an exclamation mark.
[Episode!]! represents an array of Episode objects. Since it is also non-nullable, you can always expect an array (with zero or more items) when you query the appearsIn field. And since Episode! is also non-nullable, you can always expect every item of the array to be an Episode object.
```

Now you know what a GraphQL object type looks like, and how to read the basics of the GraphQL type language.

Comment: how it relates to my question?